# Writing ANTLR grammar for parsing java file

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

I am new to ANTLRWorks and I am doing my final year project. Could anyone please help me in how to write ANTLR grammar just for recognising a class in java "and printing it in any file as an output". On the same lines then I will be able to write the grammar for my project.

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Creating all required java classes from grammar.

Execute
`java -cp antlr-3.3-complete.jar org.antlr.Tool Java.g`

OR

`java -jar antlr-3.3-complete.jar Java.g`

from the directory where you have `antlr-3.3-complete.jar` and `Java.g` file.

[Java Grammer which is compatible with Java 1.3 to 1.6](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/compiler-grammar/antlrworks/Java.g)

[This Page explains how to use Java.g file and compile it into JavaParser and JavaLexer which are required classes to generate AST tree](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1862)

Reference Resources:

[This exaplains how can we generate AST Tree](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=789)

[This explains how can we create parser and generate AST tree for any Java class. It also explains what we need to modify in original grammar file Java.g](http://www.jumbleagilemanuals.blogspot.com/2008/03/10-steps-to-beginning-to-parsing-with.html)